# Meteor Router layout and yield not showing

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

i have a problem with the Iron:router package.

I tried to render the content with this code.

```
Router.route('/',{
 name: 'tagesansicht',
 action: function () {
  this.render('page_day');
  this.layout('layout');
},
data: function () {
},
waitOn: function () {
},
});
```

the page_day.html:

```
<template name="page_day">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="inner">
            Example
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and the Layout.html:

```
<template name="layout">
    <nav>
        {{> navigation}}
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>
```

so now i have no idea why the code dont show me anything at the homepage.
I said that the route with the Path "/" render the page_day.html and the layout is layout.html but why i didnt see anything ?

EDIT:

Im getting this error in the console

```
Exception in callback of async function: MiddlewareStack.prototype.concat@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:303:7
RouteController.prototype._runRoute@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:542:11
Route.prototype.dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:856:10
Route/route@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:713:5
boundNext@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:425:16
Meteor.bindEnvironment/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:17
dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:449:3
RouteController.prototype.dispatch/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:393:7
Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:349:5
Tracker.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:237:5
Tracker.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:588:11
RouteController.prototype.dispatch/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:391:5
Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:615:12
RouteController.prototype.dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:390:3
Router.prototype.dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:1700:3
onLocationChange@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:1784:20
Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:349:5
Tracker.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:237:5
Tracker.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:588:11
Router.prototype.start@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:1777:31
Router/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:980:9
.withValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:971:17
withoutInvocation/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:428:26
Meteor.bindEnvironment/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:17
onGlobalMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:365:11
```

Answer (score 0):

In console, type
meteor add ejson

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing because you are declaring the `{{> navigation}}` template to be rendered. But this template does not exist.

To test this, comment out the this template as seen below.

```
    <template name="page_day">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="inner">
                Example
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>



    <template name="layout">
        <nav>
            <!-- {{> navigation}} -->
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            {{> yield}}
        </div>
    </template>
```